# Normalize tensors ($3$-by-$3$ matrix) so that the largest eigenvalue is 1?

Tags: tensors

I am trying to "normalize" a tensor $T$ (a $3$-by-$3$ matrix). The paper says

> ... the normalization of a tensor scales all eigenvalues so that the
>   largest one equals to $1$.

I am confused.

Should I scale $T$ with a scale $a$ so that the largest eigenvalue of $aT$ is $1$?

**Bonus**

If so, in MATLAB, is `T/eigs(T, 1)` the most efficient approach?